# $compile inside of click handler not interpolating

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set up a directive that, when its associated element is clicked, will $compile a snippet of HTML and add the result as a child of the clicked element.

Here's my JS:

```
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'World';
    })
    .directive('compileTest', function($compile) {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.bind('click', function() {
            var content = $compile('<div>Hello {{name}}</div>')(scope);
            element.append(content);  
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

In this case, {{name}} isn't ever interpolated. However, if I remove the click listener and do the $compile() and append() immediately when link is called, interpolation works. What am I misunderstanding? I figured the above should work.

Here's the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/YEGCq6

Thanks!

Comment: If you just want data binding, and dont want to link directives, use the $interpolate service. It'll work without an $apply statement. Doc: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `scope.$apply()` where the event is not forwarded from angular, therefore not in the angular life-cycle. `$apply` will update the scope and invoke the change listeners.
This works

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
})
.directive('compileTest', function($compile) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        var content = $compile('<div>Hello {{name}}</div>')(scope);
        element.append(content);  
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Arg...dad-gum $apply. Thank you! I should've known.